# How to add a colorbar to kdeplot and jointplot

Tags: python, seaborn, colorbar, jointplot, kdeplot

When generating bivariate plots like `hexbin`, pandas generates a legend explaining frequency value for each color shade:

```
pokemon.plot.hexbin(x='HP', y='Attack', gridsize=30)
```

[image: Pandas hexbin plot]

I cannot find a similar way to generate such a legend for `jointplot` and `kdeplot` in seaborn:

```
sns.jointplot(data=pokemon, x='HP', y='Attack', kind='hex')
```

[image: Seaborn hexbin plot]

```
sns.kdeplot(pokemon['HP'], pokemon['Attack'], shade=True)
```

[image: Seaborn contour lines plot]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for a [kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html?highlight=kdeplot#seaborn.kdeplot), simply pass `cbar=True`

> cbar : bool, optional
>
> ```
> If True and drawing a bivariate KDE plot, add a colorbar.
> ```

```py
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.jointplot(data=sns.load_dataset("penguins"), x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm",
                  kind="kde", cbar=True, fill=True, height=8)
```

[image]